# Парсинг ссылок с веб-страницы и сохранить результат в txt файл

Tags: python

Имею например следующий код:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='General'>
   <div class='First-class'>
    <p><a href='links what I need'>Link - links what I need</a></p>
    <p><a href='links what I'>Link - links what I</a></p> 
    <p><a href='links what'>Link - links what</a></p>
    <p><a href='links'>Link - links</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Что бы получить всё что в теге `<a href='...'></a>`:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://your/url')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('div', class_='First-class')
for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(i['href'])
```

Результат:

```
links what I need
links what I
links what
links
```

Как мне записать в файл этот результат?
Я пробую такой код:

```
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://your/url')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('div', class_='First-class')

for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(i['href'])
with open("file.txt", "a") as file_1:
    file_1.write(i['href'] + "\n")
input()
```

В результате в файл записывается только последняя ссылка, а нужно записать все.

Comment: Поместите write внутрь цикла, очевидно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='General'>
   <div class='First-class'>
    <p><a href='links what I need'>Link - links what I need</a></p>
    <p><a href='links what I'>Link - links what I</a></p> 
    <p><a href='links what'>Link - links what</a></p>
    <p><a href='links'>Link - links</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('div', class_='First-class')

with open("file.txt", "w") as file_1:
    file_1.write("\n".join(list(map(lambda i: i['href'], soup.find_all('a', href=True)))))
```